# Facebook Like Button in Pretty Photo Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, facebook-like, prettyphoto

On this site I used pretty Photo image gallery.
The problem is - when a user clicks on the facebook like button - on his news is displayed only the name of the site.
what I would like is - when a user clicks fb LIKE button on a particular image, that image is shown on his news feeds.
can you help me make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with Facebook, always ALWAYS check your website url with the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Looks like the problem is that Facebook couldn't featch the image probarly, so you will need to add a meta tag so Facebook can know the desired image for the prvded URL.

```
Ex: <meta property="og:image" content="YOUR_IMAGE_PATH"/>
```

**Update 1:**

In order to modify the Meta tag value when the user changes the gallery image, you can use the following code to do so:

```
$("meta[property=og\\:image]").attr("content", YOUR_IMAGE_PATH);
```

note that we needed to escape the `:` character as mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

**Update 2:**

you will need to alter those functions in order to make it to work:

```
    $pp_gallery.find('.pp_arrow_next').click(function(){
            $.prettyPhoto.changeGalleryPage('next');
        // here you will need to read the current image url, then assign it to our facebook line.
    $("meta[property=og\\:image]").attr("content", YOUR_IMAGE_PATH);
            $.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();
            return false;
        });

    $pp_gallery.find('.pp_arrow_previous').click(function(){
            $.prettyPhoto.changeGalleryPage('previous');
        // here you will need to read the current image url, then assign it to our facebook line.
$("meta[property=og\\:image]").attr("content", YOUR_IMAGE_PATH);
            $.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: so, how would you suggest I implement the desired bahavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054217/changing-facebook-meta-tag-content-attribute-using-jquery

Comment: in the head section I could make an if clause that will register when a user is on the "galler" page. But then how can i identify which image user has clicked on?

Comment: you will use jQuery to alter the meta tag of Facebook og:image, please check the mentioned question for more information.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer.
I must admit i am not so good with javascript. Can you please tell me where is my script (i suppose it's image gallery .js file) do i have to insert the line
$("meta[property=og\\:title]").attr("content", result.title);
?

Comment: another question - in your update you are changing the TITLE property, not the IMAGE? Or?

Comment: Fixed.
regarding where to place the code, I think it will be inside the click handler inside your PrettyPhoto js file that you are using.
sorry, I don't have it so I cannot determine where exactly to place this code.

Comment: Can you please look at the script, and tell me how and where to edit the code: here it is https://gist.github.com/3728665

Comment: from what I've seen there, you will need to add our code inside these two handlers: 
`$pp_gallery.find('.pp_arrow_next').click(function(){
     $.prettyPhoto.changeGalleryPage('next');
     $.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();
     return false;
    });

    $pp_gallery.find('.pp_arrow_previous').click(function(){
     $.prettyPhoto.changeGalleryPage('previous');
     $.prettyPhoto.stopSlideshow();
     return false;
    });`

Comment: would it be too much to ask from you to update the script and send it to me? Please :) Thx

Comment: sorry, I can't because it depends on your DOM elements, but trust me, it's so simple :)

Comment: ok, I've edited the code, but I don't understand the functionality. does it mean that now my in my head section og image attribute will be changed automatically? Do I have to do anything else with the script? Sorry, to ask so much, but I'm little confused. I don't see what I should do next and how will I reach to my image. :)

Comment: Actually what I am trying to ask is - how will our code in .js file "pick up" the image path of the image inside the code where I define images - inside the gallery on the web page?
And than where is that stored? Or is it automatically updated inside the head section with our code?

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook's OG Meta Tags

For images for instance :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourwebsite.com/img/img.png"/>
```

For more information, check out this : http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: I know it should be probably done with FB OK MT, but the problem is where to embedd them into javascript image gallery...